# How to Use Graph Cut for the Statistics of Patch Offsets for Image Completion Model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, graph, image-segmentation, max-flow

I am trying to use Shai Bagon's ([@Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410)) [Graph Cut MATLAB Toolbox GCMex](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex) for the model from Statistics of Patch Offsets for Image Completion ([Image Completion Approaches Using the Statistics of Similar Patches](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2014.2330611)).

The model is given by:

[image]

Let's say the number of labels (Shifts) is 4 (Up by 1, down by 2, right by 3 or left by 4) to make things simpler.
I am still not sure how to set the data structures (Arrays) to utilize the solver.

Does anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure my GCMex implementation supports this type of smoothness term.

If I understand correctly, you need, for each neighboring `i`, `j` to compute a *different* `L`x`L` matrix of weights. The underlying c++ package (by Boykov et al) does support this, but I did not create an interface for this option.

**Update**:

Let's say you have `n` pixels and `l` possible labels.
The current GCMex interface supports pair-wise weights of the form:

```
E(i, L(i), j, L(j)) = w(i,j) * S(L(i), L(j))
```

That is, the main "source" of pair wise penalty is a *fixed* `l`x`l` matrix `S(L(i), L(j))` that defines the penalty of assigning neighboring pixels `i` and `j` to labels `L(i)` and `L(j)` respectively. This `l`x`l` weight does *not* depend on the *location* of the pixels `i` and `j` *only* on their labels `L(i)` and `L(j)`.
The only spatial dependency comes from a *scalar* `w(i,j)` that modulates `S` by a scalar that depends on the locaiton of `i` and `j`.

However, it seems like in your case, what you actually need is a `l`x`l` matrix for each pair `i` and `j`.

I think you should look into [`void setSmoothness(smoothFnCoord cost);`](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex/blob/master/GCoptimization.h#L334).

Comment: Any chance you describe the arrays in case there ere support? So I will be able to implement in `C`?

Comment: By the way I can't up vote your answer since I don't have the proper reputation.

Comment: So the number of required elements in such array is infeasible hence the use of a function handler? I also think the model requires the weighing to be dependent of both the location and the labeling, right?

Comment: @David it seems so